# OSGi: should I have a Dao bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, dao

say I have a business application module, like user-management(um).
there're 2 ways of bundle design(as I can tell).

A.datasource, um-model, um-dao, um-service, um-wab

B.datasource, um-api, um-impl

B is what I prefer now.

some considerations I take:

1. according to "java application architecture: modularity patterns with examples using osgi", I want fine-grained over coarse-grained modules.
   However, way A is too fine-grained. Dao should be private. If another module room-booking, will query users, it should depend on module(bundle) um-api.
2. It's rare that someone will design modules(bundles) um-dao-api, um-dao-jpa-impl, um-dao-jdbc-impl, um-dao-jdo-impl. Maybe um-api, um-ldap-impl, um-avos-delegate-impl are better design.
3. datasource is a module(bundle) because I want transactions between app-modules.

So, I don't think Dao should be bundle.

any idea?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Although there is always some matter of taste here, my experience is that the following may be a good starting point:

- Separate the interface definition (API) from the implementation by putting them in different bundles. One bundle just contains the packages with the interfaces (and maybe some very basic POJOs), the implementation is put in one or more other bundles in different packages. Reason: since the implementation often changes, the dependencies tend to become more complicated over time. Putting the API packages in a separate bundle may prevent extra maintenance effort.
- Make a clear untangled layered architecture of your interface bundles and within the bundles among the packages. Reason: if the separation of functionality over packages is not clearly defined, it is likely to become even messier during its maintenance.
- If you doubt whether some functionality will only have private use for your implementation bundle or may be used by other functionality in the future, it will probably end to being used by others. However, you can always decide to define private interface packages in your implementation bundle which can easily be moved to an API bundle in the future. Nothing prevents you from using a modular architecture in your implementation bundles, although some think that this is not necessary since this part is largely invisible to the outside world (I don't agree to that).

In your situation: if you don't want other functionality to use the DAO stuff, make the interface package and put it, together with the implementation, in the implementation bundle, but don't export the package. If somehow you need to export it later, move the interface package to the API bundle.